# Bluetooth mouse suddenly stopped connecting to Android tablet

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, lenovo-yoga

I have a Lenovo Yoga Tab 3. I also have a bluetooth mouse, Microsoft 3600. Some time ago (~ 3-4 weeks) I could successfully use my mouse with my tablet. But now, after I do the pairing nothing happens, the pairing seems successful but the mouse doesn't work. The mouse still seems to work normally with OTHER devices because I can use it on my android smartphone and 2 laptops (work and home).

I have tried removing all bluetooth devices, by all I mean two devices: my bluetooth keyboard and the non-working mouse, and I also tried a factory reset.

I also did what is described in this [article](https://help.elitehrv.com/article/135-clear-bluetooth-cache-android), but it didn't help.

I started connecting all the bluetooth devices I have, they all work correctly, except the mouse. I also noticed that on the tablet it doesn't say **connected** near the mouse:

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Try deleting all paired connections on the device maually or by deleting cache and data of Bluetooth app and pair again

Comment: How do I delete the cache and data of Bluetooth app? BTW: I've performed a factory reset also

Comment: Factory reset takes care of it (sorry, missed that) . Aside, by going to apps and from 3 dot menu (depending on your Android version) selecting to display system apps >clear storage >cache and data

Comment: No, factory reset didn't help, I also cleared the data and cache of the Bluetooth Share app.

Comment: I am out of ideas. All the best

Comment: does the Bluetooth used batteries in that case change the batteries because the battery power for Android could be more

Comment: I tried the batteries, no luck!